# Javascript loop for every 2 classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I've got a small issue but not sure how to solve it by javascript/jquery. Essentially ive got several div classes but what i want to do is to create a loop to add a class on certain divs, without having to add an id on them manually but to add a id or class through the javascript code.

Heres an idea of what i mean:

```
<div></div><div></div>    
<div></div><div></div>
<div></div><div></div>    
<div></div><div></div>
```

This is what i currently have so lets say two divs will be a row. I want it so a a class is added in a certain way to make it like this:

```
<div class="green"></div>           <div></div>    
<div></div>                         <div class="green"></div>
<div class="green"></div>           <div></div>    
<div></div>                         <div class="green"></div>
```

So i am guessing it will be some sort of loop for every 2 divs then it will repeat in reverse.

Comment: I think that if you wrap in columns you can: `<div class="column"><div/><div/><div/><div/></div><div class="column"><div/><div/><div/><div/></div>`. This mixes with `:odd` (in css or jquery, like you need), and it works

Comment: FYI, indentate HTML markup like this doesn't make really sense

Comment: In a comment you and I can't indentate anything. I wish that you understand it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I'm not sure your last comment was for me BUT mine was for OP, not regarding your posted code in comment (even it's invalid one) :)

Comment: @jsg  BUT why don't you use TABLE???

Comment: @A.Wolff Its all been done automatically based on a widget i created for BetterCMS, once you added a page certain content will be taken and a be displayed on another page. So its all automatically been placed in, where i thought a bit of javascript will be used to help style the code. I can see from the comments and some of the answers people are confused on how i displayed, the layout reading it from top to bottom. Whereas i was trying to portrait i design left to right like in rows, for every 2 divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want **Zig-Zag**.

There is no need of loops. You can use `:nth-child` selector as follow:

```
$('div:nth-child(4n+1)').addClass('green'); // Selects 1, 5, 9, 13, ...
$('div:nth-child(4n)').addClass('green'); // Selects 4, 8, 12, 16, ...
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/qfmwvh1y/)

Here is the pure **CSS** Demo.

```css
body {
  width: 120px;
}
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
}
div:nth-child(4n+1) {
  background: green;
}
div:nth-child(4n) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

using jquery

Use this loop to add class after 2 div

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldxw60u7/1/)

```
 $('div').each(function(i){
   if((i%3) === 0){
    $(this).addClass('green')
   }
 });
```

using `:odd` and `:even` selector

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldxw60u7/)

```
 $( "div:odd" ).addClass( "green" );
```

for even

```
 $( "div:even" ).addClass( "green" );
```

Comment: Why so many upvotes, when this doesn't solve the issue, OP wants 0th, 3rd, 4th, 7th... div to have class

Comment: Yeah i thought of this but it wouldnt be every odd number, so the second row would be even. Is there a way to get some sort of loop for this  to reverse it after every 2 divs

Comment: Like @Tushar says, divs that needs the classes are not odds, almost in the example code. The html is reading like the humans: left to right, up to down.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude `The html is reading like the humans` Correct but doesn't make sense, i guess you know it ;)

Comment: What doesn't make sense?

Comment: @NishitMaheta Do you really understand the question. I doubt. Please read the qeustion again. See the expected output

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It sounds like OP wants columns and that's just bad markup indentation

Comment: @A.Wolff yeah, I know, it's because my comment in the main post ;)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
    <div class="element">4</div>
    <div class="element">5</div>
    <div class="element">6</div>
</div>
```

**Pure Javascript:**

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");

for (var i = 0, ii = parents.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var parent = parents[i],
        children = parent.children;

    for (var j = 0, jj = children.length; j < jj; j++) {
        var elem = children[j];
        if (j % 2 === 0) {
            elem.classList.add("highlight");
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/bipakub/edit?html,css,js,output)

## OR

**jQuery:**

```
$(".element:odd").addClass("highlight");
```

[Demo](https://jsbin.com/muvejafake/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You can grab your divs with a for loop using childNodes () javascript function. If the index is odd then you can apply manually your class.

something like this:

```
var nodes = parentElement.childNodes();

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) continue;

    nodes[i].className = "green";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If just for show different background, you may use css nth-child(even) or nth-child(odd), as should sample in the table:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC} 
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```